# Write the string name of the Input key

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In my game, the user can set a key to open the game-console.

I want to show an info during the game to the user, that they can open the console by pressing the key, they've set before.

For example:

The default key for the console is f1. Then it should show:

> Press F1 to open Console

If the user sets the `C` key, it should write:

> Press C to open Console

But i don't find any way to write down the key, the user set before, by code.

Edit:

I'm sorry that it wasn't that clear what i mean.

I added a screenshot of the Input-Configuration (which is the default Unity Input-Configuration).

In this Configuration the user can set a key for `OpenConsole` by double clicking on `f1` (in the `Primary` row).

In Unity i can check if a specific Button is pressed like this:

```
if (Input.GetButtonDown("OpenConsole"))
{
...
}
```

But what i want is, that i can show the user which key they have chosen for `OpenConsole`. Something like this:

```
text.text = "Press the " + WhateverTheUserSet + " Key to open the Console!";
```

[image]

Comment: **How** does the user set the key code? Can you add your script code please?

Comment: @derHugo i don't have any script so far, its been set by the default unity thing.

Comment: You might be interested in writing a complete [custom in-game Input Manager](https://www.studica.com/blog/custom-input-manager-unity-tutorial) with that you would be able to parse the `KeyCode`s into your displayed string

Answer (score 0):

Okay, your question isn't clear as to how the default / redefined key is set / changed by the user but I'll give two solutions based on two scenarios:

**Scenario 1: Assumes you are asking the user what key to use via an onscreen "Redefine Key" page.**
In this situation, you will probably use something along the lines of `Console.ReadKey()` where you are capturing the user's keyboard press.  You end up with a key code which could be one of around 100 keys on a keyboard.  You will need to store internally a mapping between keycode and "text".  If they user had pressed F1 and this is keycode (say 232) then you will use the mapping to give you the string "F1" which is what you display on screen.  You would store the keycode in config for use in the game and for peristance between launches of the game.

**Scenario 2: Assumes the user edits a config file and sets the value in there.**
In this situation, you need the mapping going the other way.  If the config file includes (by default):

```
ConsoleKey=F1
```

Then you need a similar internally stored mapping but in the other direction.  If the user changes the value to "A" then this would need to map to a keycode (e.g. 65).  The user can change the config file and the mapping will tell the user what key to detect in game.  You can display the same text as in the config file for your on-screen "info".

If you can be clearer in how you are intending to implement this then we can provide a clearer answer.

Comment: i added a screenshot and made some edits to the question, i hope its more clear now!

Comment: Thanks, the screenshot suggest we're looking at Scenario 1 above.
I think some existing code would really help.

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately, Unity doesn't have a way to check which keys are assigned from the input manager.  If you need more control, you'd need to implement your own key mapping solution.